# How to polyfill fetch and promise with webpack 2?

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-promise, webpack-2

How to polyfill [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) and [promise](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise) for [Webpack 2](https://webpack.js.org/)?

I have a lot of entry points, so Webpack 1-way to add them before each entry point is not desired solution.

Comment: Why don't you just include the polyfills as a single entry ? They are polyfills so no module will import/require them.

Comment: Do you mean to load polyfills as single file before bundles (I don't have SPA. 1 page = 1 bundle. Thats why i have a lot of entry points)? If yes - it is one more GET request =/ Anyway, nice hint, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Regardless of how many entry points you have, you should have a separate file for your vendor files, such as frameworks (react, angular, whatevs) and any libraries you always need but are rarely going to change. You want those as a separate bundle so you can cache it. That bundle should always be loaded. Anything you include in that bundle will always be available but never repeated in your chunks if you use it with the commonChunksPlugin.

Here's a sample from an app I've done (just showing relevant config options):

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    client: 'client',
    vendor: [
      'react',
      'react-addons-shallow-compare',
      'react-addons-transition-group',
      'react-dom',
      'whatwg-fetch'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/build/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor', 'manifest']
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Bounty will expire soon, so i give it to you, as most voted answer, but if someone has another approach, your are  welcome ;)

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the bounty

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm not understanding correctly, but couldn't you just add `babel-polyfill` before the rest of your entry points in your webpack config?

```
module.exports = {
   entry: ['babel-polyfill', './app/js', '/app/js/whatever']
};
```

Comment: entries is object: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries/#multiple-entries So I have to copy-paste them a lot between keys. I was looking for something, importing them for each entry point automatically.

Comment: So in my experience, you need to either add the `import 'babel-polyfill'` into the application startup, usually an `index.js` file.. or add it to each entry point manually in webpack. I highly recommend using the former as most application's have a single point of startup and you don't have to keep adding the polyfill.

Comment: FYI: babel-polyfill doesn't include fetch